# Tuple not list in Jupyter

Tags: python, class, types, jupyter-notebook, tuples

I am writing a class for quaternions. I would like to give the quaternion coordinates as a tuple, not as a list. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
class Quaternion(object):

    def __init__(self, elements):
        if len(elements) != 4:
            raise ValueError("Quaternion init vector must be of length 4.")
        self.elements = elements
```

What to do to write elements as a tuple not as list. When I try to run my program in Jupyter everything is good, but I must type `Quaternion([1,2,3,4])` - so it is not a tuple, but list.

Comment: Put them in `()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `*args` and `**kwargs`? Search those two in the Python documentation to get an overview of the possibilities. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Don't use `*args` when you already know how many arguments you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the way you call it to:

```
Quaternion((1,2,3,4))
```

use the `tuple()` function to convert the list to a tuple:

```
class Quaternion(object):

    def __init__(self, elements):
        if len(elements) != 4:
            raise ValueError("Quaternion init vector must be of length 4.")
        self.elements = tuple(elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a tuple using *any* sequence, including `list`s, in the body of the function.

```
def __init__(self, elements: Sequence):
    if len(elements) != 4:
        raise ValueError("...")
    self.elements = tuple(elements)
```

However, since a quaternion *must* have 4 components, be explicit about that in `__init__`, and let a class method produce an instance from an "arbitrary" sequence.

```
def __init__(self, a, b c, d):
    self.elements = (a, b, c, d)

@classmethod
def from_sequence(cls, elements: Sequence):
    try:
        a, b, c, d = elements
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Quaternion init vector must be of length 4.")
    return cls(a, b, c, d)
```